# Circumventing "not enough storage" to backup iPhone error on mac

Tags: iphone, backup

I've backed up my iPhone to my Mac for years, with no issue.  However, recently, on macOS bigSur 11.4 on an M1 Air, my iPhone XS has thrown up a "Not enough storage on this mac" to backup error.

I have 26 GB free, and I've never seen a backup take up more than 10 GB.  Most space on my iPhone is taken up by a third party podcasts app with lots of downloads, but that's not new and it hasn't caused issues before, and anyway, the downloaded not be backed up to my Mac.  Is there a way to get around this error warning, given it shouldn't really be happening?

[image: disk space]

Comment: Launch Disk Utility, click on your Data drive on the left, then tell us the figures  for 'overall' in the box top right, then Used, Other Volumes & Free, in the 'thermometer' in the middle. e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXMl.png

Comment: @Tetsujin done! thanks for suggestion

Comment: OK, thanks. That is looking pretty seriously full, but before you start deleting things… try a reboot, allowing no apps to auto-reopen afterwards. Try the backup immediately. You might just get enough to do this once. Long-term, you really, really need to get some space back. That's dangerously full; add the backup & you are going to get disk full warnings frequently & ultimately kill your SSD years before it normally would. You should aim for 15 - 20% free space at all times - ironically, more on a small drive like that.